# Static type variable, member constraint, compiler bug? ("Attempted to parse this as an operator name, but failed")

Tags: f#, inline, f#-3.0

Compiles:

```
let inline f< ^T when ^T : (static member (<<<) : ^T * int -> ^T) > (x : ^T) = x <<< 1
```

Does not compile:

```
let inline f< ^T when ^T : (static member (>>>) : ^T * int -> ^T) > (x : ^T) = x >>> 1
```

Errors:

1. Attempted to parse this as an operator name, but failed
2. Unexpected symbol '>' in member signature. Expected ')' or other token.
3. A type parameter is missing a constraint 'when  ^T : (static member ( >>> ) :  ^T * int32 ->  ^T)'

Adding spaces doesn't help; this line yields the same compiler errors:

```
let inline f< ^T when ^T : (static member ( >>> ) : ^T * int -> ^T) > (x : ^T) = x >>> 1
```

I've searched both the documentation and the specification, to no avail.  Is this a bug?  Is there some way to include the `>` characters in the member signature?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure looks like a bug.  It's ugly, but one workaround is to use the long form of the operator name:

```
let inline f< ^T when ^T : (static member op_RightShift : ^T * int -> ^T)> (x : ^T) =
    x >>> 1
```

Comment: Ah, thanks.  I thought I had tried that without success, but obviously there was something else wrong, because this works just fine.

Comment: @phoog - you might have used `op_GreaterGreaterGreater` instead, which can't actually be used symbolicly.

Comment: No, I definitely used op_RightShift, and the compiler seemed not to recognize `>>>` with that constraint.  Maybe I typed `op_LeftShift` instead of `op_RightShift`, though, or something else was wrong.

Answer (score 6):

Do you even need an explicit constraint? This works just as well:

```
let inline f (x: ^T) : ^T = x >>> 1
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for your answer; I forgot to include that in the question.  It was actually in an earlier, much longer version of the question, but I decided in favor of brevity before posting.  I did have a reason to use the explicit constraint.  I don't remember what it was, exactly; in the end I decided to solve my problem entirely differently.  The problem was to write code to generically decompose either IEEE single or IEEE double into sign, exponent, and mantissa parts; for now I'm just using a type alias that I can change as needed.  I may return to the generic approach later.